# Realizar una consulta con diferentes rangos de fecha

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un caso en el que necesito hacer una suma condicional de un rango de fecha y otra con otro rango de fecha, esto estoy intentando:

```
SELECT M.idinsumo INSUMO
,SUM(CASE WHEN C.tipo = 1 AND M.fecha BETWEEN '17-05-1990 07:00:00' AND '04-07-2021 03:00:00' THEN CANTIDAD ELSE cantidad END) INICIAL
,SUM(CASE WHEN C.tipo = 1 THEN CANTIDAD ELSE cantidad END) FINAL
FROM movsinv M
LEFT JOIN conceptos c         on c.idconcepto = m.idconcepto
WHERE C.tipo IN (1,2)  AND M.fecha BETWEEN '17-05-1990 07:00:00' AND '04-07-2021 23:59:59' 
                  AND M.idalmacen= 3
GROUP BY M.idinsumo
```

**Lo que obtengo:**

```
INSUMO           Inicial     Final 
001001           21.0000    21.0000
001002            1.0000    1.0000
001003            1.0000    1.0000
001004            1.0000    1.0000
```

**Lo que espero conseguir:**

```
INSUMO           Inicial     Final 
001001            1.0000    21.0000
001002            1.0000    1.0000
001003            1.0000    1.0000
001004            1.0000    1.0000
```

M.fecha es un campo datetime

Comment: Una cosa, en los dos case when independientemente de la condición devuelves CANTIDAD, ¿eso por que es? Es como poner SUM(CANTIDAD) sin tanta historia.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, es lo mismo. Lo que no logro hacer es que en sum(case when..)   sea una sumatoria distinta al sum(cantidad).

Comment: Quita `else cantidad` de ambos case y así es posible que te devuelva resultados diferentes.

Comment: Lo intenté, pero me seguía dando datos iguales o no reales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logré resolver mi problema, les dejo mi solución, ojalá que a alguien le pueda servir. Hice una subconsulta.

```
SELECT M.idinsumo INSUMO
    ,(SELECT SUM(cantidad)
FROM movsinv F
LEFT JOIN conceptos c on c.idconcepto = F.idconcepto
WHERE C.tipo IN (1,2)  
             AND F.fecha BETWEEN '17-05-1990 07:00:00' AND '05-07-2021 03:00:00' 
             AND F.idalmacen = M.idalmacen
             AND F.idinsumo = M.idinsumo                   
GROUP BY F.idinsumo) INICIAL -- SUBCONSULTA
        ,SUM(cantidad) FINAL 
FROM movsinv M
LEFT JOIN conceptos c on c.idconcepto = m.idconcepto
WHERE C.tipo IN (1,2)  
             AND M.fecha BETWEEN '17-05-1990 07:00:00' AND '05-07-2021 23:59:59' 
             AND M.idalmacen = 3 
             AND M.idinsumo = '002013'                 
GROUP BY M.idinsumo,M.idalmacen
```

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas y aportes.